Tool tip not show permanently in all columns
I use this code in node red
const series = chart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
   name: "Series 1",
   xAxis: xAxis,
   yAxis: yAxis,
   minBulletDistance: 10,
   valueYField: "value",
   sequencedInterpolation: true,
   categoryXField: "sensori",
   calculateAggregates: true,
   tooltip: tooltip,
}))
var tooltip = am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
   getFillFromSprite: false,
   getStrokeFromSprite: true,
   autoTextColor: false,
   getLabelFillFromSprite: true,
   //labelText: "[bold]{valueY}[/]}"
});

series.columns.template.setAll({
   tooltipText: "[bold]{valueY}",
   width: am5.percent(90),
   tooltipY: 0
});
series.columns.template.setAll({
   showTooltipOn: "always",
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
});


type here

but it show tool tip only in one column permanently, not in all columns.

How to fix?
I have check in docs possible  methods , but cant get work.
